# Choosing $k$ consecutive numbers out of $n$ numbers

Tags: probability

What is the probability to choose $10$ consecutive numbers out of the numbers $1-100$ ?

And what is the probability for the general case given $k$ consecutive numbers out of $n$ numbers ?

I think the answer should be $\frac{n-k+1}{\binom{n}{k}}$ but i am not sure !

Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is correct. To see that $\ \ n-k+1\ \ $ is actually correct, consider the special case $k=1$

Comment: The number os possibilities are $\binom{n}{k}.$ There are $n-k+1$ cases with consecutive numbers. So your answer is correct.

Comment: @Peter I have added a small rigorous proof for that. Let me know what you think about that.

Comment: @paulplusx I do not think that this exercise needs a rigorous proof. Since we have the Laplacian case, we only have to count the "good" cases and the possible cases. And to determine the numbers is really easy and obvious.

Comment: @Peter It was not that much obvious to me, probably because of my inexperience. Hence I added that, so that people like me can easily understand that :-) and yeah I'll look up for that Laplacian case since I don't know what it is :-)

Comment: @paulplusx It just means that every elementary event has the same probability to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, you are **correct**.

For $k$ consecutive numbers you form groups of $k$ numbers (which are consecutive).

Let us consider a set of $n$ numbers $[a_1, a_2, a_3, ....., a_n]$. Now the $1^{st}$ group will be:

$[a_1, a_2, a_3, ....., a_k]$

$2^{nd}$ group wil have the first element $a_1$ removed  and $a_{k+1}$ added. If we continue this till the last ($x^{th}$) group we get:

$\underbrace{[a_1, a_2, a_3, ....., a_k]}_{1^{st}}\ ,\underbrace{[a_2, a_3, a_4, ....., a_{k+1}]}_{2^{nd}}\ ,.......,\underbrace{[a_{x}, a_{x+1}, a_{x+2}, ....., a_{k+(x-1)}]}_{x^{th}}$

So the last number of the last group would have to be $a_{n}$. Hence if we compare the subscripts of the last number obtained, we get:

$k+(x-1)=n \implies x=n-k+1$

So we have a total of $n-k+1$ groups, each having $k$ consecutive numbers and the total number of ways to select $k$ numbers from a pool of $n$ numbers would be ${}^{n}C_{k}$.

Thus, the probability would be $\displaystyle\frac{n-k+1}{\binom{n}{k}}=\frac{n-k+1}{{}^{n}C_{k}}$.