# Number of adjacent sequences in natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, arithmetic

I was working on a probability exercise and then I get a little bit confused. The question was **probability of getting a straight flush in 52 cards deck**, so I was wondering how many scales there are for each suit. I came up with this table
$$\begin{array}{c| c c c c c }
1 & A& 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2 & 2& 3 & 4& 5& 6 \\
\vdots & \vdots & & & & \vdots \\
10 & 10& J& Q& K& A 
\end{array}
$$
So total number of scales in a suit is $10$. Could this results be generalized so

> Given $n$ natural numbers (we choose to not consider $0)$ how many consecutive line of $m$ elemets there are ($m\leq n $)?

This table reasoning could also apply so
$$\begin{array}{c| c c c c c }
1 & 1& 2 & 3 & \cdots & m \\
\vdots & \vdots & & & & \vdots \\
n-m+1 & n-m+1& n-m+2& n-m+3& \cdots& n 
\end{array}
$$
So we can conclude that the number we are searching is $n-m+1$? Is this a valid proof, there are other methods to prove this? Sorry if the question look silly, thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't think I've heard "scale" being used like this before. I think the usual playing-card terminology would be "a straight" (implying $5$ cards, usually). If they all have to be the same suit, it would be a "straight flush". Usually in English, the "colour" is different to the "suit" - there are two colours, but four suits. Your reasoning about the generalisation is correct, and I think it's a nice proof! See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2905031/473276).